# Prevent ffmpeg from taking over stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ffmpeg, fiber

When I do `system "ffmpeg -i just-do-it.mp4 -ab 96k -ar 22050 -qscale 6 output.flv"` ffmpeg takes over the ruby process till the job is done, which sometimes take a long time. I've tried using threads amd fork in Ruby to no avail, also `system` equivalent commands like `exec` `%x[]` I also tried the latest Fibers in ruby 1.9.2, but I don't think I'm using it properly.

My question is how to run two ffmpeg processes from ruby concurrently?

EDIT:

```
fork do
  fork do
    system "ffmpeg -i you-know.mp4 -ab 96k -ar 22050 -qscale 6 #{Time.now.sec}.flv"
  end                            

  fork do
    system "ffmpeg -i bangbang.mp4 -ab 96k -ar 22050 -qscale 6 #{Time.now.sec}.flv"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork/exec` is the right solution.  Since forked processes inherit the parent processes fopen file handles/etc., you'll have to close (or redirect) the file handles you don't want children processes to use.

For example:

```
# this will print nothing, but yes is running as a forked process
# you'll want to `killall yes` after running this script.
fork do
  [$stdout, $stderr].each { |fh| fh.reopen File.open("/dev/null", "w") }
  exec "yes"
end
```

Ok, some comments on the code you posted.  The outer `fork` is pointless.  Just fork the two ffmpeg process from the main process.  Maybe write a helper function like:

```
def ffmpeg(mp4)
  fork do
    [$stdout, $stderr].each { ... }
    exec "ffmpeg -i #{mp4} ..."
  end
end

ffmpeg("you-know.mp4")
ffmpeg("bangbang.mp4")
```

Comment: I added the fork code above, but that doesn't work, obviously I'm missing something, can you help? Thanks!

Comment: @Senthil, don't use `system` (which is just forking/execing/waiting), use `exec`.  Remember to redirect STDOUT/STDERR/etc.  See example snippet above.

Comment: Thanks that worked great! Although the "yes" seemed to have gone amok and is using 96% of cpu process. Maybe I didn't close it properly, but the ffmpeg is now running forked, so that's good.

Comment: Yea, I know what you mean about the outer fork, I came upon it while Googling on Ubuntu forums and I put it there as a hail mary.

Comment: @Senthil: Great.  As far as `yes` is concerned, writing to `/dev/null` is very quick so `yes` can consume all the CPU with `write` calls (this can be verified by `strace`).  So I suspect you did redirect stdout correctly.

Comment: Hmm this seems to make the benchmarking not possible, I suppose that makes sense using `fork`. Any idea how to benchmark this, ruby-prof perhaps? Thank for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @senthil:  Do you mean how can you benchmark the call to ffmpeg?  You exit ruby-land as soon as the call to `exec` occurs (your process is replaced by `ffmpeg`), so there is no way to benchmark at that point.  The overhead of forking should be negligible though, so I wouldn't be too concerned about benchmarking this particular of your application.  You'll notice if you run `pstree` while your application is running that the only children processes of your process are `ffmpeg` (not `ruby`)

Comment: Yea, you're right about Benchmark being useless there, so I decided to just tail `top` based on the output pid and it has a time column. :)

Comment: Be aware that fork() is not available on JRuby, so if you ever run on a different vm, this might not work. There are some projects that help you run stuff in the background. Take a look at http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/

Answer (score 0):

Try the subprocess gem - that's what I'm using now for dealing with process forking and finding it much easier to use.

E.g.

```
    work_list.each do |cmd|
        process = Subprocess::Popen.new(cmd)
        process.run
        process.wait
        #puts process.stdout
        #puts process.stderr
        puts process.status
    end
```